# how to remove/stop script from being executed in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

i want to make `<script> ...... </script>` as text(or not executable code) which is returned from another page using ajax.

```
<div id="page"></div>

 $.ajax({
        url: "http://example.com",
        type: "GET",
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "text/html",
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            $('#page').append(response);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
```

my problem is that the above code executes the script present inside the `response` if error occurs my furthur page will not execute and program will stop.  so i wanted to make `script not executable`. **how can i do it?**

or how can i make any `code inside script blank`

suppose my script is like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // some erroneous code or some resource load which failed verification
  console.log('i want to remove every code');
</script>
```

Comment: your question is not clear. can you please reframe it

Comment: i just want to remove or replace <script>anycode</script> from script which is returned from ajax response

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do 3 steps

1. converting received htmlstring in to DOM element like

   ```
     parser = new DOMParser()
               doc = parser.parseFromString(response, "text/xml");
   ```

or use

```
var doc = document.createElement('div');
doc.innerHTML = response;
```

2. Then finding all script tags init

   `allScriptTags = doc.find( "script" )`
3. After that run loop on allScriptTags and remove all script tags

> ```
> allScriptTags.forEach(
>   function(item) {
>       item.remove();
>       // or item.parentNode.removeChild(item); for older browsers (Edge-)
> });
> ```

Finally,

```
     $.ajax({
            url: "http://example.com",
            type: "GET",
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: "text/html",
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                parser = new DOMParser()
                doc = parser.parseFromString(response, "text/xml");
                allScriptTags = doc.find( "script" )
                allScriptTags.forEach(
                    function(item) {
                        item.remove();
                        // or item.parentNode.removeChild(item); for older browsers (Edge-)
                });
                $('#page').append(doc);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status) {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
```

I hope it will help.

If it doesn't work, try to use string manipulation to remove  tags from remove htmlstring.

***Plunker*** : http://plnkr.co/edit/OUi8U945MIMFZoWQpBGy?p=preview

Comment: ok @hemaKumar, what is var = new DOMParser() is it api or in built in jquery?

Comment: Follow this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser

Comment: You can use 

var doc = document.createElement('div');
doc.innerHTML = response;

without parser extension.

Comment: hi @hemakumar  i have tried your answer but it is giving this error => Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token, i don't know why can you make a fiddle please

Comment: without ajax is ok for demo

Answer (score 0):

Use "<pre>" or  (html5 support) tags to show the code as is.